# How can I edit the opcode of an instruction?

Tags: .net, cil, il, mono.cecil

I'm writing an application in .NET to edit the instructions of any method. I want to put ldstr in OpCode and a string in Operand. Mono.Cecil allows me to set the Operand, but the problem is that the OpCode is a ReadOnly property. Is there any way to edit the OpCode?
For this I use this code:

```
Dim assembly1 As AssemblyDefinition
assembly1 = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(rute)
For Each modDef In assembly1.Modules
    For Each typeDef In modDef.Types
        For Each mDef In typeDef.Methods
            For i = 0 To mDef.Body.Instructions.Count - 1
             mDef.Body.Instructions(i).OpCode.Code = Mono.Cecil.Cil.Code.ldstr
             mDef.Body.Instructions(i).Operand = "Text"
            Next
        Next
    Next
 Next
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To change an code of instruction you can use `Mono.Cecil.Cil.OpCodes` enum.

```
mDef.Body.Instructions(i).OpCode = Mono.Cecil.Cil.OpCodes.Ldstr;
```

If you want to insert or emit new instructions, you can use `Mono.Cecil.Cil.ILProcessor` object.

```
mDef.Body.GetILProcessor().InsertBefore(targetInstruction, Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, "New string"));
```